# Creating a file through a dangling symlink with vi

Tags: unix, vi, symbolic-link

This is the content of my typescript file,

```
/mac>ln -s non_exist ~/link
/mac>vi ~/link
Hi!
I am a link.
/mac>cat ~/link
Hi!
I am a link.
/mac>cat non_exist
cat: non_exist: No such file or directory
/mac>exit
```

Can anyone tell me what actually happened here?

This did not create a file but the following did:

```
/mac>ln -s non_exist link
/mac>vi link
Hi!
I am a link.
/mac>cat link
Hi!
I am a link.
/mac>cat non_exist
Hi!
I am a link.
/mac>exit
```

Comment: `cat ~/non_exist`  The link refers to a relative path, and the relative path of `non_exist` from `~/link` is `~/non_exist`

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links are relative paths.  If `~/link` is a symbolic link to `non_exist`, then the full path of the target of the link is `$HOME/non_exist`.  When you open `~/link` with `vi`, it creates the file named `non_exist` in your $HOME directory rather than your current directory.